# Java object doesn't seem to be inheriting the variables of it's parent class

Tags: java

I'm doing a class assignment on code zinger in Java, the requirements are as follows:

Create a class `ProblemSolution` with following characteristics

> A public method 'solution' without parameters and return type is int.
> Create object of class 'Student' inside 'solution' method and return
> the value of “rollNumber” from the class 'Student'.

Output

```
10001
```

I have two files in the tree structure, "ProblemSolution", which has this code :

```
import java.util.*;

public class ProblemSolution {

    public static int solution () {
        Student r = new Student ();
        return r.rollNumber;
    }

}
```

and "Student", which has this code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Student {

    public static int student () {
        int rollNumebr = 10001;
        return rollNumber;
    }

}
```

When I try and run this code I get this error:

```
ProblemSolution.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    return r.rollNumber;
            ^

symbol:   variable rollNumber
location: variable r of type Student
```

As far as I can tell object "r" either isn't actually being created, or it just isn't inheriting the code from the "Student" file. How can I get this code to give the desired output?

Comment: Hi you need to declare rollNumebr as field variable and student as a constructor not a method

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I think you need to study a bit more on how Java classes are defined, and specifically how instance variables are defined in classes.  You haven't defined any instance variables on your classes.  Your variables are all local to the methods you've defined.  Whatever you define inside those methods disappear when the method exits.  Also, your methods are `static`, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this is me studying how Java classes are defined, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
public class Student {

    public static int student () {
        int rollNumebr = 10001;
        return rollNumber;
    }
}
```

you want:

```
public class Student {

    private final int rollNumber;
    Student (int rollNumber) {
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
    }

    public int getRollNumber(){return this.rollNumber;}
}
```

and

```
public class ProblemSolution {

    public static int solution () {
        Student r = new Student (10001);
        return r.getRollNumber();
    }

}
```

Follow something that can teach you the difference between [methods](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm), [constructors](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm), local variables and [fields](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/fields.html).